# Unity Netcode (MLAPI) Host Moving And Client Connecting, But Client Not Moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Recently started using Unity Netcode (MLAPI) to try and make a Multiplayer Racing game, but I am having some troubles. This is my first time making a multiplayer game, so I'm fairly new to this stuff.

What is happening:
The Client connects to the Host perfectly fine, and the wheels move like the car is going to move, but the client is unable to move at all. The host can move just fine, and is able to collide with the client, and the client can view it all, but the client just isn't moving. I assume this is something to do with NetworkTransforms but I really unsure at this point.

Below is my attached movement script for the vehicles:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class VehicleMovement : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private const string HORIZONTAL = "Horizontal";
    private const string VERTICAL = "Vertical";

    private float horizontalInput;
    private float verticalInput;
    private float currentSteerAngle;
    private bool isBraking;
    private float currentBrakeForce;

    [SerializeField] private float motorForce;
    [SerializeField] private float brakeForce;
    [SerializeField] private float maxSteeringAngle;

    [SerializeField] private WheelCollider frontLeftWheelCollider;
    [SerializeField] private WheelCollider frontRightWheelCollider;
    [SerializeField] private WheelCollider rearLeftWheelCollider;
    [SerializeField] private WheelCollider rearRightWheelCollider;

    [SerializeField] private Transform frontLeftWheelTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Transform frontRightWheelTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Transform rearLeftWheelTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Transform rearRightWheelTransform;
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (IsLocalPlayer)
        {
            GetInput();
            HandleMotor();
            HandleSteering();
            UpdateWheels();
        }
    }

    private void HandleMotor()
    {
        frontLeftWheelCollider.motorTorque = verticalInput * motorForce;
        frontRightWheelCollider.motorTorque = verticalInput * motorForce;
        currentBrakeForce = isBraking ? brakeForce : 0f;
        ApplyBraking();
    }

    private void ApplyBraking()
    {
        frontRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentBrakeForce;
        frontLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentBrakeForce;
        rearRightWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentBrakeForce;
        rearLeftWheelCollider.brakeTorque = currentBrakeForce;
    }

    private void HandleSteering()
    {
        currentSteerAngle = maxSteeringAngle * horizontalInput;
        frontLeftWheelCollider.steerAngle = currentSteerAngle;
        frontRightWheelCollider.steerAngle = currentSteerAngle;
    }
    private void GetInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis(HORIZONTAL);
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis(VERTICAL);
        isBraking = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
    }

    private void UpdateWheels()
    {
        UpdateSingleWheel(frontLeftWheelCollider, frontLeftWheelTransform);
        UpdateSingleWheel(frontRightWheelCollider, frontRightWheelTransform);
        UpdateSingleWheel(rearLeftWheelCollider, rearLeftWheelTransform);
        UpdateSingleWheel(rearRightWheelCollider, rearRightWheelTransform);

    }

    private void UpdateSingleWheel(WheelCollider wheelCollider, Transform wheelTransform)
    {
        Vector3 pos;
        Quaternion rot;
        wheelCollider.GetWorldPose(out pos, out rot);
        wheelTransform.rotation = rot;
        wheelTransform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

My prefab consists of Transform, Rigidbody, [The script above], NetworkObject, NetworkTransform, and NetworkRigidbody.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khsz3EGu3TI) is an Unlisted YouTube Video that hopefully visually shows the issue.

Any and all help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In general if you use physics don't set anything via `Transform` at all but rather only through the rigidbody and in that case you only would want the rigidbody to be synced, not the transform directly

Comment: So would you say I need to modify my Transforms into rigidbodies?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out under the Package Manager there an optional import in "Netcode for GameObjects" hidden under "Samples" called "ClientNetwork Transform".

This completely solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[NetworkTransform](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/components/networktransform#clientnetworktransform) is server authoritative by default, meaning only servers can update the NetworkTransform object.

We can get around this by creating a client network transform object that changes the permissions to client authoritative:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode.Components;

[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class ClientNetworkTransform : NetworkTransform
{
    protected override bool OnIsServerAuthoritative()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this currently, as this process is no longer accurate above today, can be found [here in the documentation](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/components/networktransform/index.html#clientnetworktransform)

ClientNetworkTransform#

NetworkTransform always synchronizes positions from the server to the clients and position changes on the clients are not allowed. Netcode for GameObjects comes with a sample containing a ClientNetworkTransform. This transform synchronizes the position of the owner client to the server and all other client allowing for client authoritative gameplay.

The ClientNetworkTransform lives inside the Multiplayer Samples Utilities package. You can add this package via the Package Manager window in the Unity Editor by selecting add from Git URL and adding the following URL:

```
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.multiplayer.samples.coop.git?path=/Packages/com.unity.multiplayer.samples.coop#main
```

Or you can directly add this line to your manifest.json

```
file:= "com.unity.multiplayer.samples.coop": "https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.multiplayer.samples.coop.git?path=/Packages/com.unity.multiplayer.samples.coop#main"
```

I  could never get:

```cs
    protected override bool OnIsServerAuthoritative()
```

to run as a solution, but found a [closed issue on git](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.multiplayer.samples.coop/issues/685)

Is it broken again or am I using it wrong?